# Openshift - Applying RunOnlyAs SCC to pods within a deployment

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, openshift

I have an SCC defined that lets the `developer` user run containers as UID `1015`:

```
    kind: SecurityContextConstraints
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: developer
    allowPrivilegedContainer: false
    runAsUser:
      type: MustRunAs
      uid: 1015
    seLinuxContext: 
      type: MustRunAs
      uid: 1015
    users:
    - developer
```

This SCC works fine when I create a pod directly as the `developer` user:

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: test-1-0
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1015
      containers:
      - name: test-1-0
        image: test-image:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secret-dir
          mountPath: "/secrets"
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: secret-dir
        secret:
          secretName: test-1.0-configs
```

However, when I transition this to a deployment, I get an error. Here's my YAML:

```
kind: "DeploymentConfig"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  name: "test-1-0"
spec:
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: "test-1-0"
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1015
      containers:
      - name: test-1-0
        image: test-image:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secret-dir
          mountPath: "/secrets"
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: secret-dir
        secret:
          secretName: test-1.0-configs
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    name: "test-1-0"
```

And the error I receive:

```
Error creating: pods "test-1-0-1-" is forbidden: unable to validate against any security context constraint: [securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 1015: UID on container test-1-0 does not match required range. Found 1015, required min: 1000050000 max: 1000059999]
```

It's as if the deployment is deploying pods NOT as the user I created the deployment with. Is there any way to resolve that?

Comment: do you already tried this?: https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#enable-images-to-run-with-user-in-the-dockerfile +  Login to your OpenShift master via SSH or $ docker exec -i -t origin /bin/bash
su -
oc edit scc restricted
# Change the runAsUser.Type strategy to RunAsAny

Comment: @FrancoRondini You should avoid editing the original ``restricted`` SCC as you are changing the default upon which a lot of stuff relies. The reason for the SCC is to allow you to create different permission sets and apply them selectively to specific service accounts. Overriding the system provided defaults is always a bad idea.

Comment: Not that it matters, but scc.seLinuxContext.uid is not a valid field.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton good point!  what I wrote was proposed in some tutorials/git repo of intro-examples, but your clarification is super useful. By the way I have also opened [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651767/openshift-kubernetes-disoriented-by-the-various-configuration-files) to which I have seen your comment and I would be grateful if you could find the time for the complete answer. thanks again.

Comment: If in the other question you are having issues with running commands without referencing the config file explicitly, then I can help. Normally you wouldn't need to care about the master config files. If you really want to understand what they are for, you are better off reading through the OpenShift docs at https://docs.openshift.org/latest/welcome/index.html as there isn't a simple answer beyond that they dictate the global configuration for the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably better to dictate what SCC is to be used for the deployment via a service account.

First off create the SCC. Using what I have tested as an example, I created `uid1000.json` containing.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "SecurityContextConstraints",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "uid1000"
    },
    "requiredDropCapabilities": [
        "KILL",
        "MKNOD",
        "SYS_CHROOT",
        "SETUID",
        "SETGID"
    ],
    "runAsUser": {
        "type": "MustRunAs",
        "uid": "1000"
    },
    "seLinuxContext": {
        "type": "MustRunAs"
    },
    "fsGroup": {
        "type": "MustRunAs"
    },
    "supplementalGroups": {
        "type": "RunAsAny"
    },
    "volumes": [
        "configMap",
        "downwardAPI",
        "emptyDir",
        "persistentVolumeClaim",
        "projected",
        "secret"
    ]
}
```

Then ran:

```
oc create -f uid1000.json --as system:admin
```

Need to be admin to do that.

Next I created a service account in the target project just for running the application which needs this SCC.

```
oc create serviceaccount runasuid1000
```

I now say that anything run as this service account should use the new SCC.

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user uid1000 -z runasuid1000 --as system:admin
```

Again need to be admin to do that. The `-z` option means use current project, so make sure you are in the right one.

Finally I patch the existing deployment config.

```
oc patch dc/minimal-notebook --patch '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccountName": "runasuid1000"}}}}'
```

If necessary, due to config change trigger being disabled, trigger a new deployment:

```
oc rollout latest minimal-notebook
```

This will force the container to run as uid 1000, overriding what the image even says it should run as according to `USER` definition.