# Openshift/Kubernetes: disoriented by the various configuration files

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, configuration-files, openshift-origin

I'm learning [openshift origin](https://docs.openshift.org) , in the master container I found a number of config files:

```
[root@openshift] cd /var/lib/origin
[root@openshift origin]# find . -name *kubeconfig
./openshift.local.config/node-localhost/node.kubeconfig
./openshift.local.config/master/admin.kubeconfig
./openshift.local.config/master/openshift-master.kubeconfig

[root@openshift origin]# find . -name *config.yaml
./openshift.local.config/node-localhost/node-config.yaml
./openshift.local.config/master/master-config.yaml
```

I found out these files also inspecting the origin container:

```
 $ docker inspect 671fb8df3752 | grep config
            "--master-config=/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.config/master/master-config.yaml",
            "--node-config=/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.config/node-localhost/node-config.yaml"
                "/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.config:/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.config:z",
                "Source": "/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.config",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.config",
                "KUBECONFIG=/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.config/master/admin.kubeconfig",
                "--master-config=/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.config/master/master-config.yaml",
                "--node-config=/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.config/node-localhost/node-config.yaml"
```

Could you help me to schematize / summarize the role and use of each of these files?

Specifically when executing commands of this type:

```
oadm policy add-scc-to-group anyuid system:authenticated --config=/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.config/master/admin.kubeconfig
```

they must be directed to each of the configurations I have found or only to the specific one?

Comment: Normally when you run that command, you wouldn't need to supply ``--config`` option. What specific docs are you reading which says to use that option? It also isn't a good practice to grant ``anyuid`` to all authenticated users. You would usually grant it to the specific service account in the project that needs the extra rights to run an image as any user ID.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton about specific doc: [openshift-v3-showcase](https://github.com/sebastianfaulhaber/openshift-v3-showcase/tree/master/websphere-liberty) session:  [B. Installation,OpenShift Dedicated + link: https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#enable-images-to-run-with-user-in-the-dockerfile]

Comment: without --config:`[root@moby ~]# oadm policy add-scc-to-group anyuid system:authenticated
Error from server (Forbidden): User "admin" cannot get securitycontextconstraints.security.openshift.io at the cluster scope: User "admin" cannot get securitycontextconstraints.security.openshift.io at the cluster scope (get securitycontextconstraints.security.openshift.io anyuid)`  with --config it works: `[root@moby ~]# oadm policy add-scc-to-group anyuid system:authenticated --config=/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.config/master/admin.kubeconfig
scc "anyuid" added to groups: ["system:authenticated"]`